# Rotate A towards B with limited turn rate

Tags: c#, mathematics, rotation

I want to rotate A towards B with a fixed turn rate per second.
My math skills are very limited and I have no clue in how to accomplish this.

Best Regards

Comment: How does your game represent rotations? Angles? Complex numbers? Quaternions? Transformation matrices?

Comment: Both Quaternions and matrices. I am using the Xenko engine which is pretty similar to XNA

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of linear interpolations, they give you a point between point A and point B, by a given normalized time **t** (between 0 and 1). Since they are linear, it will be made on a fixed rate.

The given example is with **Unity**, but the same maths are applied anywhere. Lets say I want to interpolate between Vector A and Vector B on 'x' seconds, I need a normalized reference to pass, so what we can make is to have a t value beginning at 0, and add it the value of the last frame's duration, divided by the duration of the interpolation. So, if without the division, t would reach 1 in a second, divided by the given duration will make t reach 1 on the given x seconds.

```
public Transform target;
public float duration;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) StartCoroutine(Rotate(target.position - transform.position), duration);
}

IEnumerator Rotate(Vector3 direction, float s)
{
    Quaternion originalRotation = transform.rotation;
    Quaternion destinyRotation = Quaternion.Euler(direction);
    float n = 0.0f;

    while(n < 1.0f)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(originalRotation, destinyRotation, t);
        t += (Time.deltaTime / s);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

The interpolation's formula is very simple, if you want to make interpolations of other types of data (Vector, Color, Doubles, etc.) make sure those data types can have '-, +, and multiplication' operators applied upon each other. The given example is with a float, but the algorithm is the same for any data type:

```
/// Make sure to pass a t between 0 and 1, or you can internally clamp t inside this function.
public float Lerp(float a, float b, float t)
{
    return a + ((b - a) * t);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unity actually has a specialized method for this exact use-case: [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html). But that would be a very Unity-specific answer to a question which doesn't appear to be about Unity.

Answer (score 1):

First code your AngleTo function:

```
    public static float AngleTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    {
        return (float)Math.Atan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2);
    }
```

Start with your UnitPosition and derive NewAngle from the PositionToFace.

```
// Note: This may be backwards, in which case swap the arguments
// Note: This angle may be off by some constant, such as Math.Pi/4;
NewAngle = AngleTo(
               UnitPosition.x, UnitPosition.Y, 
               PositionToFace.x, PositionToFace.y);
```

Now, during each update, add TurningRate to your UnitFacingVector until it is facing the NewFacingVector

```
if(isTurning)
{
    if(Math.abs(UnitAngle - NewAngle) < TurningRate)
    {
        UnitAngle = NewAngle;
        isTurning = false;
    }
    // NOTE: you'll eventually want a TurningRight or TurningLeft instead of just isTurning)
    else
    {
        UnitAngle -= TurningRate;
    }
}
```

And that should do it; and best of all, it'll do it without re-calculating ArcTan several times (which is expensive.)

When having multiple moving entities, I'd probably only update "NewAngle" every second or so so that you can leverage the most out of your ArcTan calls. This can eventually be a more sophisticated approach where you track if you and/or the target are moving and update more or less frequently based on that possibly.